# Result differs in iPod and higher devices

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am facing some issues in my app. I have developed an app which has many formulae's and calculations. The result which is generated is perfect in iPhone 5s and above, but the calculation result varies in 4s and iPod. I never came across such problem. Thank You

Comment: are you using `CGFloat` to do the calculations? their accuracy will differ from 32bit to 64bit devices

Comment: no i haven't used CGFloat @Fonix

Comment: well without some code we cant really help you, but it sounds suspiciously like a 32/64bit problem, since 5s and above support 64bit while lower is 32bit

Comment: yeah it is 32/64bit problem , i dint find any solution on google so posted here. The code very lengthy and has many classes. Not possible to post the code. @Fonix

Comment: can you not debug a bit to narrow down your code where the solutions start to diverge? then maybe post something applicable, otherwise i dont know if anyone can really know exactly what your problem might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with a solution for 32bit/64bit devices. I just replaced all the int , NSInteger, intValue , long , longValue to double and doubleValue. That it.